# How can I compute the rotation of a vector of a finite-dimensional complex vector space through an arbitrary angle?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, vectors, rotations

I am comfortable computing the rotation of vectors through arbitrary angles in finite-dimensional real vector spaces using rotation matrices. How may one compute the rotation of a vector in a finite-dimensional complex vector space by an arbitrary angle?

Comment: Could you give an example of such complex vector space?

Comment: C^n such as C^2, C^6, etc.